# Using Scringo in Android app

Tags: android, scringo

I'm using `Scringo` in my Android app because I want to enable chat between users, but I want to disable option on Invite for users to send text messages and that popup window that is shown every time when I open app.

Also I'd like to now how to remove those test examples from my app, like those "`imaginary`" people on Radar that are there only for test but they were shown every time when user go to Radar.

I searched all over the web to find some instructions on how to customize Scringo in my app, and I didn't find anything about it and I can't send them messages because that section on the site is under construction.

And there are not many post all over the web about Scringo.

There are some about using it in `IOS` and thats it.

**SOLVED:** Well I sent message to Scringo developers and to disable the "invite" feature is not possible at the moment, so I disabled it on ScringoResources, found `scringo_panel.xml` and looked for the `android:id="@+id/scringoPanelInvite"` and set up its `android:visibility="gone"`. And I disabled Invite freature for showing in Scringo panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling the "Invite" feature is currently not possible, as you can see on the dev zone of Scringo (dev.scringo.com). Send a feature request to support@scringo.com and I'm sure they'll try to support it in the next version...

The test/debug/"imaginary" users you see are there because you called "Scringo.setDebugMode(true);", if you delete that line you won't see them.

Comment: thanks. I sent them a message about my problem. Hope that they'll help me. :) I solved problem with showing PopUp window every time when I start my app, I disable it for showing in activity in Resources/scringo_welcome_popup  where I set for Relative layouts visibility:invisible.

Comment: regarding welcome popup, isn't it simpler to disable it using your account at dev.scringo.com? There's a selection in the General section of each app you created, set it to "once" or "never" and you got it. You can also use Scringo.DisplayParams - set "welcome" to false and pass it as a parameter to the Scringo.init method...

Comment: I tried using account at dev.stringo.com but it is not working.